# Slow authentication over SSH

Tags: ssh

A while ago, one of our sysadmins accidentally ran a recursive chown from `/`. So I had to run `rpm --setugids` on every package listed on `rpm -qa`. That solved the biggest problem, which was logging on the server.

After that incident, I noticed that ssh to that server was taking way too much time. I logged using `ssh my-server -l username -vvv` and, after entering the password, I get a

> debug1: Entering interactive session.

for about 1 minute.

I've checked all file permissions under `/etc` and `/var`, everything seems to be fine. What else can I do to troubleshoot that problem?

Comment: Have you enabled more verbose logging? Have you tried to skip profile from being parsed using `ssh -t myhost bash --noprofile --norc` to see if that speeds up the login process?